# Crontab No module named Pandas

Tags: python, cron

For some reason, Cron won't process this and keeps telling me that pandas is not installed (it is whenever I normally run my code)

I'm getting this mail:

```
  Subject: Cron <user@Justins-MBP-4> PYTHONPATH=/Users/user/Library/Python/3.6/lib/python/site-packages python  ~/downloads/random/milbtrans.command
X-Cron-Env: <SHELL=/bin/sh>
X-Cron-Env: <PATH=/usr/bin:/bin>
X-Cron-Env: <LOGNAME=user>
X-Cron-Env: <USER=user>
X-Cron-Env: <HOME=/Users/user>
Date: Tue,  8 May 2018 11:18:01 -0400 (EDT)

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/user/downloads/random/milbtrans.command", line 2, in <module>
    import requests, csv, pandas, openpyxl, datetime, time
ImportError: No module named pandas
```

Changed Pandas to be fixed but now getting this error:

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/user/downloads/random/milbtrans.command", line 2, in <module>
    import requests, csv, sys, pandas, openpyxl, datetime, time
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/__init__.py", line 19, in <module>
    "Missing required dependencies {0}".format(missing_dependencies))
ImportError: Missing required dependencies ['numpy']
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: How was pandas installed? If it was in a virtualenv, for example, you'd have to run it in that env. You could `print(pandas.__file__)` to see where it is on your system. If its not in a system directory, then it is some sort of local install.

Comment: That command tells me it's located here: `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/__init__.py`

Comment: I'm not familiar with which toolset puts stuff in `/Library/Frameworks`. What change did you make to fix the pandas problem?

Comment: I changed the PYTHONPATH code to be to the right directory in the comment above

Comment: (Can't help but notice that installing third-party packages to the system Python is not a great idea; a virtualenv makes things much easier to control and understand.)

Comment: You could compare `sys.executable` and the `__file__` path to one of the modules that does import on both sides to see if the paths are different.

Comment: Is this a user cron or system cron?

Comment: No idea what kind of cron this is (first time using this). I've heard about a virtualenv but I have no experience doing that and don't want to screw something up. And I have no idea how to compare those two files :(

Comment: I think that you have more than one python installed (or at least more than on `site-packages` from a virtual env). The python you run on the command line is different than the one in the cron job. So, just poking around trying to see which paths lead where.

Comment: Is there a simpler way to do this? All I want to do is execute a Python file once a day but I keep getting into a rabbit hole of errors.

Comment: Assuming you created this with `cron -e` you are doing a user level cron. But its still in a restricted environment (smaller PATH, fewer env variables). As a minimum, use an absolute path to python (whatever `which python3` gives you). I wrote a little program that dumps python env to /tmp.  https://pastebin.com/g3uLmuvg you could diff your local and cron envorinments to see the difference. For instance, on my machine, `python3` was 3.6 in my shell but 3.5 in cron because of some hacking I've done. If you install one and run in another, badness happens.

Comment: There's a slim chance adding a #! to the top of your script to the python install you expect might help.

Answer (score 5):

You haven't posted your crontab, but I suspect you are not using the correct path to Python 3.6.  Your cron error email says the PATH cron is using is /usr/bin and /bin.  Your cron command calls just "python".  So cron will use its PATH to try and resolve "python".

Is an executable or link to Python 3.6 available in either of those locations?

What do you see if you run: `$ /usr/bin/python` or `$ /bin/python` from your own login?  I'm guessing that one, the other, or both would start a different version of Python (i.e. Python 2.x.x)

1. Find out exactly where python3 is installed.  Example (your results may be different):

`$ which python3
/usr/local/bin/python3`

2. In crontab, use this same absolute path when you specify the python executable and the path to your script (also using an absolute path).

crontab

```
0 0 * * * /usr/local/bin/python3 /Users/user/downloads/random/milbtrans.command
```

I suggest you try it like this first without the PYTHONPATH.

You could also be more elegant and manage environment variables for the cron execution context  (i.e. exporting a correct PATH environment variable via the crontab itself or a "wrapper" shell script) which would also solve the problem, but based on what you've shared here I believe this is the simplest way to address your current issue.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue on Ubuntu 18.04.

For me the fix was to have crontab call a shell script which then executes the python script. Also had to set *HOME* and *PYTHONPATH* environment variables:

crontab:

```
# Execute shell script and pipe stdout and stderr to a log file
# Which will enable you to see what's going on
* * * * * <your_path>/yourscript.sh  >> <your_path>yourscript_cron.log 2>&1
```

yourscript.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo yourscript.sh called: `date`
HOME=<your_home_dir>
PYTHONPATH=<path_to_dist_packages>
cd <path_to_your_python_script>
<python_executable> ./<your_python_script> 2>&1 1>/dev/null
```

Funny enough, this shell wrapper method is the way I settled on for scheduled tasks on windows in the past as it gives you the best debugging and flexibility possible.

Comment: (Debian systems) Seeing as this will be run by cron. It is also worth noting the right formatting of the scripts/script names and ownership. See: https://serverfault.com/a/754104

If you test with a config for every minute e.g. */1. You won't have issues. However if you designate a specific time every day I had to apply the correct formatting as indicated above for it to work.

Comment: I've since switched to using PyEnv (https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv) and will likely use this next time I have to use Python from a Crontab as it greatly simplifies management of packages and environment for python.